# How do you search all Redhat repos for a package

Tags: redhat

I have RHEL7. How do I search ALL repositories (including those I'm not subscribed to with subscription-manager) for any and all packaged with "dav_svn" in the name?

I am required to use RHEL7 for this project. I must have SimpleSAMLPHP installed, which required PHP 5.6+. RHEL7 comes with PHP 5.4. So, to upgrade it, I used the subscription repos to install PHP73. That required removing HTTPD and installing HTTPD24. Another requirement: Subversion must be installed. Subversion required mod_dav_svn. I believe that mod24_dav_svn is required when using HTTPD24. However, I cannot find that package in any repository. There are so many to look through. That is the reason that I want to knwo how to search all the repositories at once - especially onces I did not subscribe to.

UPDATE: I do not believe this has an answer. I scheduled a meeting with Red Hat to discuss it and I was told that it simply does not exist. You must enable a repo to search it. So, to search all repos, you must enable all repos. You cannot search all repos, including all those that are not enabled. Further, I was told that there is no account type that can enable every single repo available.

Comment: Redhat provides a searchable database for customers, [as answered here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/6869/2823)

Comment: @GeraldSchneider That searches my installed subscriptions by default. I have to manually select each repo one at a time to search them. I have absolutely no clue what repo I want. That is why I want to search ALL of the repos at the same time.

Comment: Who cares if you can't access a repo that is not part of your subscription? The package you want isn't going to be in there anyway.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Read before you comment. The package I need is not in a repo I am subscribed to. I need to find out whcih repo I need to subscribe to. So, I need to search all repos that I am NOT subscribed to. Then, when I find the proper repo, I can subscribe to that one.

Comment: I did read before I commented; you should do the same. It seems you are confusing "subscribe" to a repo with "enable" the repo. You are subscribed to many repos which are not enabled (see `subscription-manager repolist`). You can search all of them using the answer I have already posted. And I expect you will find your desired package in there.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I *have* searched through all repos I have subscribed to. I am *not* confusing subcribe with enable. I am *not* subscribed to a repo which provides the package that I need. Therefore, I need to find out which repo contains that package so I can subscribe to it and then enable it. I do not understand why this is difficult to understand.

Comment: After digging around a bit more, I think the problem is that no repo contains the package you're looking for. I found a [third party software collection](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/sclo/sclo-subversion19/) that contained such a package, but I don't think that was built for httpd24. You may be out of luck. Of course you could also go with RHEL 8 and have everything you need. It's not clear why you have to use RHEL 7.

Answer (score 4):

You can temporarily enable all repos to perform a search, for example:

```
yum --enablerepo=\* search dav_svn
```

Though sometimes a repo may not be available to you, either because your subscription doesn't allow for it, or it's offline, or whatever other reason. You can temporarily disable such repos and retry:

```
yum --enablerepo=\* --disablerepo=rhel-7-server-failing-repo search dav_svn
```

(If there are multiple repos to disable, use a comma separated list.)

This may take a long time to run at first while all the metadata for all the repos is synced.